# how to access the object in ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

**IMAGE**[This is how ist's displayed on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysjAc.png)
I want to access the object part to display the data using EJS. I have failed to reach the object data.

My Schema

```
let Subject = mongoose.Schema({
  name:[],
  crh:[]
});

let Program = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  semester: Number,
  subject:[Subject]
});

let School = mongoose.Schema({
      name:{
        type: String,
      },
      program:[Program]
})
```

POST METHOD TO ACCESS THE DATE FROM THE DB

```
router.post('/view',(req,res) =>{
  let school = req.body.school;
  let semester = req.body.semester;
  let program = req.body.program;
  All.find({name:school,"program.name":program,"program.semester":semester},(err,record) =>{
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!record){
      req.flash("error","We couldn't find any relevant document! ");
      res.redirect('/admin/view');
    }
    if(record){
      console.log(record);
      res.render("./admin/viewSub",{find:record});
    }
  })
})
```

Consoled data! How do i access the data of the object from ejs. I want to display the data inside the object in table. I just want to know how to access it, when i try to use "." to reach the points; i am unable to reach the data.

```
[ { program: [ [Object] ],
    _id: 5a9045474b530750a4e93338,
    name: 'sose',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: can you give the output of `found[0].school` in

Comment: @Rupesh i have edited the above code, i played around for a while, still stuck at the same place. That's how it looks now.

Comment: I have attached a picture too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<ul>
   <li><%= find.name %></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <%for (var prog in find.program){%> //to fetch data from array of array
   <li><%= prog.name %></li>
   <li><%= prog.semester %></li>
   <ul>
      <% for (var sub in prog.subject){%> 
      <li><%= sub %></li>
      <%}%>
   </ul>
   <%}%>
</ul>
```

Comment: remove that commented line `//take to fetch data from array` from code

Comment: It’s still blank and and exactly same as the image before.

Comment: try this `<p><%=find%><pi>   ` on ejs page ,show me the output

Comment: Still the same. The same list style dot is coming and then blank.